# Value to set for android:maxLength for editText field to avoid SQLInjection in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have been creating an android app regarding a student form, I have knowledge about `SQLInjection` and therefore want to avoid it.

Hence I can't get the value I should set to these fields for proper working as well as protecting the app from `SQLInjection` attacks.

I have tried the `android:maxLength=120` for `Firstname` fields. But I notice that its actually very long.

Comment: Please explain! What you need? exactly.

Comment: I just want to know the value(int value) that I want to set for maxLength attribute of xml for fields like firstname and so on for basic form field.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the SQL injection should be filtered from Backend ,For example in PHP you can use PreparedStatements and insert data using it to prevent SQL Injection. Now from what I understand, you can filter out special characters which will never be used in a first name, using regex.
Setting length wouldn't be helpful in this case